# Login Integration Testing Good and Bad Password

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, integration-testing, cypress

I am writing Cypress Integration Test for UpdatePassword. One reason I wanted one whole test: We had a minor bug before, when the user enters a bad password, and then fixes it up, the Submit Button would not be Reenabled to press.

What is the best way design, should I create whole or separate?

I  can create one whole full test case, like this

1. User inputs bad password
2. Check for red label warning html element
3. Then Put in good password
4. Confirm Success

---

Or separate into two

**Test Case 1**

1. User inputs bad password
2. Check for red label warning html element

**Test Case 2.**

1. Then Put in good password
2. Confirm Success

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say two tests:

**Test One**

1. User enters bad password
2. Check the warning label has the correct information

**Test Two**

1. User enters bad password
2. User enters good password
3. Check the confirm button is enabled

If you want, you can go on to a third test that contains the steps from test two plus clicking the button and checking that the proper update successful message returns.

This approach does mean more repetitive tests, but it has the advantage of tests not relying on any prior tests.

Comment: why did people vote down my question? trying to learn, can you vote up? thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 - Have you read the FAQs about asking in the Help site? (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help) This community tends to downvote questions users find too simplistic or too opinion-based rather than commenting or making edit suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the decision of whether to create single or multiple test scripts covering single/multiple test cases is a crucial decision.

I would suggest combining multiple validations in a single test to create a real-world scenario where the user sees different validation messages for different attempts, and then one attempt gets successful.

- The only challenge that will arise is the failure of the whole script if any of the assertions fail in between before the last step, and as a result, the rest of the code will not be tested or executed.
- An automation strategy is to use "soft assertions" to continue the
  script execution in case any of the assertions fail in between. This
  will allow you to cover multiple validation scenarios in a single
  test script.

**Test Example**

1. User inputs bad password 1
2. Assertion for validation 1 *(soft assertion; in case it fails, it moves to execute the 3rd step)*
3. User inputs bad password 2
4. Assertion for validation 2 *(soft assertion; in case it fails, like a typo in the message, it moves to execute the 5th step)*
5. Enter a valid password
6. Confirm Success

Answer (score 0):

**First Option 1: One Whole Test Case**

**Pros:**
This approach mimics the real user experience more closely, as the user might enter a wrong password first and then correct it.
It ensures that the entire flow is working properly from beginning to end.

**Cons:**
If one part fails, it might be a bit more complex to identify the exact issue since everything is in one test.

```
describe('Update Password Test', () => {
  it('should handle bad and good password', () => {
    cy.visit('your-login-page-url'); 

    // User inputs bad password
    cy.get('input[type="password"]').type('badPassword');
    cy.get('.warning-label').should('be.visible'); // Verifyred label warning

    // Then Put in good password
    cy.get('input[type="password"]').clear().type('goodPassword');
    cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('be.enabled'); // Confirm Submit Button Reenabled
    // Confirm Success
    cy.get('.success-message').should('be.visible'); 
  });
});
```

**Second Option 2: Separate into Two Test Cases**

**Pros:**
Easier to pinpoint where an error occurred.
The test cases are more modular and maintainable.

**Cons:**
It may not reflect the actual user behavior as closely.

```
  describe('Update Password Test', () => {
  it('should handle bad password', () => {
    cy.visit('your-login-page-url'); 

    // User inputs bad password
    cy.get('input[type="password"]').type('badPassword');
    cy.get('.warning-label').should('be.visible'); 
  });

  it('should handle good password', () => {
    cy.visit('your-login-page-url');

    // Then Put in good password
    cy.get('input[type="password"]').type('goodPassword');
    cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('be.enabled');
    cy.get('.success-message').should('be.visible'); // Confirm Success
  });
});
```

**Conclusion:**
If you want to mimic the real user experience and test the whole flow in one go, Option 1 might be more suitable.
If you prefer maintainability and easier error tracking, Option 2 with separate test cases would be a better choice.